# Is possible do not fetch eager relation in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have relation annotated as following:

```
@OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
```

Is possible to do not fetch this relation without changing default fetch type to lazy? 
I ask obout it because I improve existing application and I don't want to change existing entities and their annotations. In my case I don't need to fetch this relation and fetching it is very computer power consuming so I would like to avoid it. 
One way to solve it is createing second redundant entity which does not have this relation. Is there a better way?

I use Hibernate as persistence provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure on this, Try specifying the fetch type explicitly in your query, some thing like this:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(ParentClass.class);
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
crit.setFetchMode("childProperty", FetchMode.LAZY);
```

Comment: I don't want to remove old entity. There is a lot of Views in application which uses that old existing entity. I make only one new View where I prefer lazy fetch. I don't want to edit existing entity because there is a lot of complicated logic in application and I am afraid that I can screw up sth.

Answer (score 2):

JPA Implementers such as Hibernate use the global fetch plans like these to create SQL's (to load entities later for e.g., for loading entity by Id instead of creating SQL's every time when required) at EntityManagerFactory bootstrap time
and there is not yet any configuration to override these global fetch plans.
The two solutions that come to mind are

1. *Change your mapping* - 
   Highly recommended and cannot be stressed enough. 
                    Eager fetch plans should be scrutinized at all times and  avoided at best. Believe me this is experience talking :-)
2. *Use Criteria API* - as Illustrated by @Amit - **however** this would mean
   that you would need to change the *access pattern* in your code.If your Parent entity is related to another Entity in the graph and you simply call getParent from the Root entity, it will load the related childrens of Parent too in one shot (using a prebuilt join query if you are using Hibernate) and this would be useless. Whereever you need to relate Parent entity, mark it Lazy and avoid it's getter - intead use Criteria query.